# Is there a separate cable for camera in A1707

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Recently I replaced the battery and keyboard in my 15" MacBook Pro A1707. Unfortunately, the built in camera Has now disappeared from the system (System report says there's no connected camera).

I tried different solutions from the web (resetting SMC, PRAM, killing VDCAssistant process) but none of them helped me. Finally I tried to disassemble my mac again to make sure I don't have any cables left unconnected - everything seems to be connected properly.

I'm pretty much sure I couldn't break anything - I unplugged lcd cable right before I started replacement and didn't touch it till the very end.

But maybe there is another (separate) cable connecting top part with lcd to logic board which I somehow didn't notice?